# Coredata / SWIFT get records with relationship

Tags: swift, core-data, relationship

Still in  trouble with core data relationships.

Example :

Entity User (idU, NameU = attributes)
Entity Device (idD, NameD = attributes)

[core data model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9aoI.png)
**Question** : I have a Nsset issue when i create a new device linked to user. i think it is related to the many-many relationships

***still not working UPDATE :***

**code :**

```
 @IBAction func addDeviceBoutonAction(sender: AnyObject) {

        print("Creation Device debut")
        var nbCharacteres = Int((newDeviceNameTextField.text?.characters.count)!)
        if currentUserName == "" {
           print("Erreur creation device / currentUserName = Vide --> Abort")
          }
          else if nbCharacteres == 0 {
            print("Erreur creation device / newDeviceNameTextField = Vide --> Abort")
          }
          else
          {
          // init du MOC
          let MOC = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
        // creation de la requete sur l'entité User avec un predicat : on recupere que les infos du user selectionné dans le pickerViewUser (on 
        // travaille avec la variable globale currentUserName qui a été initialisée lors du  didSelectRow du pickerViewUser)
        let fetchRequestUser = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "User")
        print("Creation device / trace currentUserName = \(currentUserName)")
        let userPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "userName == %@", currentUserName)
        // On colle le predicat dans la requete
        fetchRequestUser.predicate = userPredicate

        var requestError: NSError?
        let existingUser = (try! MOC.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequestUser)) as! [User]
         print("Creation device / trace existingUser[0].userName = \(existingUser[0].userName)")
        // il faut passer par l'ID plutot que le nom
        // firstUserFound de type User
         let firstUserFound = existingUser[0]
                print("Creation device firstUserFound = \(firstUserFound)")    

        // Insertion d'un nouveau Device dans la base  (relationship n to n entre Device et User)
       let existingDevicesForThisUser = firstUserFound.mutableSetValueForKey("device")

       // Create Item Record
       let newDevice = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Device",inManagedObjectContext: MOC) as! Device
       //if let newDevice = createRecordForEntity("Device", inManagedObjectContext: MOC) {
        // Set Attributes and values
        newDevice.setValue(NSUUID().UUIDString, forKey: "deviceId")
        newDevice.setValue(newDeviceNameTextField.text, forKey: "deviceName")
        newDeviceNameTextField.text = ""
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        //newDevice.setValue("Device \(newDevice.count + 1)", forKey: "deviceId")
        // Set Relationship
        print("avant relationhips")
        newDevice.setValue(firstUserFound, forKey: "users")
```

**Error :** 
Creation Device debut

Creation device / trace currentUserName = toto

Creation device / trace existingUser[0].userName = Optional("toto")

Creation device firstUserFound =  (entity: User; id: 0xd000000000080000  ; data: {
    devices = "";
    userId = "8A32EAC6-87E2-4CF1-8265-5E7A32ABCEBB";
    userName = toto;
})

avant relationhips

2016-04-02 13:55:13.065 testcoredatarelationships[1568:370426] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unacceptable type of value for to-many relationship: property = "users"; desired type = NSSet; given type = testcoredatarelationships.User; value =  (entity: User; id: 0xd000000000080000  ; data: {
    devices = "";
    userId = "8A32EAC6-87E2-4CF1-8265-5E7A32ABCEBB";
    userName = toto;
}).'
*** First throw call stack:

line which is wrong :
newDevice.setValue(firstUserFound, forKey: "users")

extension Device {

```
@NSManaged var deviceId: String?
@NSManaged var deviceName: String?
@NSManaged var cards: NSSet?
**@NSManaged var users: NSSet?**
```

}

Comment: Do you already have the Jack instance? Are your relationships bi-directional (they should be)? Show a picture of the entity model.

Comment: hi Wain, in fact, for now it is just dummy data. I put the core model (some fields are different but it should be ok)

Comment: i would like to create a real example just to understand how relations ships between entities is working. so i have created a simple view with this simple core data but i cannot achieve it (need help to finish)

Answer (score 1):

You're using a many to many relationship so the easiest way to get jacks devices is to get jack (with a fetch request) and then to ask it for its devices. This navigates the relationship so you don't need another fetch.

It's possible to directly fetch devices who have a relationship to a user with a specific name but it's more complicated to do that.

Comment: user and device is a n to n relationship / device and card should be 1 to n (several card for 1 device but each card is dedicated to one device = reference for example)

Comment: About your 2 answers : how Will you do that ? Because user do not have device attributs ? About the second case, how Caen you fetch directly with device ? Do you have à y example of both possibilities ?

Comment: If you have a user instance, `jack` then it's just `jack.devices`

Comment: Why do you say : It's possible to directly fetch devices who have a relationship to a user with a specific name but it's more complicated to do that.
Any example ?

Comment: Because you can do a fetch request but it's one of the most complex kinds of predicate to get right. Hopefully a predicate like `ANY user.name == %@` will work for you

Comment: Ok Thanks wain buy it is quite difficult to understand why it is so complex to get this information (so easy with sql request). This coredata model with Only 2 entitities and 2 attibutes.

Comment: The complexity is just because of the multiplicity of the relationship. It's trivial if you navigate the relationship.

Comment: Because you're trying to add a single item as the full relationship by the looks of the error message

Comment: I have updated the question (still in issue / about nsset ...)

Comment: Did you auto-generate the managed object classes? You should. It creates API for you to add objects to relationships.

Comment: Yes i think so. I did not create the class myself. Menu/create managed object...i think it is trivial issue ... But hard for beginners